# Prevent python multiprocess Process from accessing stdout

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that is calling an external library in a child process, this external library is printing status updates in the from of sys.stdout.write calls.

Its interface has no option for suppressing them, is there any way to redirect a child process' stdout to hide it?

The program is using multiprocessing.Process the code snippet would be slightly unweildy as the call to stdout.write happens a few classes deep inside a generator.

Comment: How are you calling that external library? (I mean... how is that _child process_ created?) Through the `multiprocess` library? Through `subprocess`? It'd probably help if you could paste the chunk of code that makes that call to an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Sending to /dev/null:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull)
```

Comment: what exactly are you sending?

Comment: Its not "sending" but more "redirecting".

Comment: @Juergen, I am on about the object, how will the OP redirect the child process stdout because that is the question not just how to redirect all stdout?

Comment: I must admit, that I did not read all of the conversation. I only had the impression, that redirection was the intent of the answer. When you do this at the child process, it should work. When you want to do it from the parent process, you better go a different way.
Edit: Now I see that it seems that the output should be redirected after the child has been started. That is not so simple ...

Comment: @Juergen,yes but the question is how to do that using multiprocessing. It is not like using subprocess where you can simply redirect stdout of the process.